# using sqlite3dbm with mrjob for map reduce

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

I have a sqlite3dbm which store data in key-value pair. I need to process it using `mrjob`.
When I run my code `xyz.py my_db.db`,  mapper fn doesn't work properly.

```
def mapper(k,val):
  for word in val:
     yield(word,k)
```

I get null for `k`

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://mrjob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html#defining-command-line-options). You need to configure to your job appropriately to read from a database file.